# Recursive sum of an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, sum

Hello I'm learning recursion in C and I am trying to find the sum of the elements.

This is my main:

```
int main()
{


    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int sum;
    sum = arr_sum(arr,4);
    printf("\nsum is:%d",sum);



    return 0;

}
```

And my recursive function:

```
//n is the last index of the array

int arr_sum( int arr[], int n )
{ // must be recursive

    int sum = 0;
    //base case:
    if (n < 0) {
        return sum;
    } else{
        sum = sum + arr[n];
    }
    //make problem smaller
    arr_sum(arr,n-1);
}
```

The output is:

```
sum is :0
```

Comment: 1) In the `else`-case your function does not return anything, 2) The result of the recursive call is not used at all.

Comment: You're not doing anything with the result of the recursive arr_sum call.

Comment: yes I see where I went wrong now. Every time I called the function it would reset sum

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add a third argument, which is the running total calculated so far (start it as `0`).

When you recursively call the function, pass the running total.

```
int arr_sum( int arr[], int n, int sum )
{ // must be recursive

    if (n < 0) {
         return sum;
    }

    sum += arr[n];

    return arr_sum(arr, --n, sum);
}
```

Alternatively, you change it to not require passing the `sum` variable like so.

```
int arr_sum( int arr[], int n )
{ // must be recursive

    if (n < 0) {
         return sum;
    }

    return arr[n] + arr_sum(arr, n - 1);
}
```

In this way, it is similar to finding a number in the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: That fixed it! Added a sum parameter and it is working now. Is there a way to do it with only those two parameters?

Comment: @MarcusLorenzana Yep, [try this](http://codepad.org/H2zIdLKt). The code I posted isn't the most elegant solution, but if you're having difficulty with recursion it may be easier to comprehend.

Comment: Thanks! Just wondering because the sample exam has it in such a way.

Answer (score 14):

Try this for your recursive function:

```
int arr_sum( int arr[], int n ) { 
  if (n < 0) {
    //base case:
    return 0;
  } else{
    return arr[n] + arr_sum(arr, n-1);
  }
}
```

you need to add your n-th case to your n-1 case until you get to the base case.

Comment: Thank you this works nicely as well

Answer (score 3):

Try this modified version of your program and work out on pen/paper the way it flows through. Hope it helps.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//n is the last index of the array
int
arr_sum(int arr[], int n )
{
    //base case:
    if (n == 0) {
        return arr[0];
    }

    return (arr[n] + arr_sum(arr,n-1));
}

int
main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int sum;

    sum = arr_sum(arr,4);
    printf("\nsum is:%d\n",sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I guess I get confused at times the order of execution in memory with recursion but I understand this bit perfectly now

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning any thing from else part.You also have return from that.
like.

```
return arr_sum(arr,n-1)+arr[n];
```

so this call the function again and again until n will be zero.

you got my point?

Comment: Got you, thanks. My function was returning to 0 each call

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that everytime when your recursive function calls, it initializes the sum as `0`.

Declare `sum` outside the recursive method that will solve the problem.

Comment: Ahh okay that makes sense. It is working now with sum outside. Is there a way I could do this recursively with only the parameters (int arr[], int n)?

Comment: @MarcusLorenzana　Why don't you look at the duplicate question? It's all there.

Comment: @Marcus Lorenzana :If you found useful, tick it as correct. I didn't get you. Now itself you are using only those parameters.

Comment: Oh thanks didn't notice that

Comment: do not declare sum outside your function. That is not proper recursion. You do not even need to have a variable named sum.

Comment: @imran His requirement is to use only two parameters. Can u suggest me a better way than this?

Comment: @Maximin see my answer, this could have easily been googled.

Comment: yeah just saw among comments in this question. http://codepad.org/H2zIdLKt

Comment: I kind of just wanted to be nudged in the right direction so I could understand it more