# Why this recursive function doesn't work?

Tags: c, function, average

I have to do a code that print the average of the numbers in an array. For sum, I use a function that I used in another time to calculate the recursive sum, and only divide by n later. But it doesn't work.

Why should I do?

```
int aveg(int *a, int n){
    if (n == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return ((aveg(a, n - 1) + a[n-1]) /n);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"it doesn't work”* is a useless problem description. Does it not compile? Does it crash? Does it give wrong results? Have you *debugged* the problem?

Comment: What @MartinR said. Plus, fix a [mre]

Answer (score 3):

Because `(a + b + c)/3 != ((a/1 + b)/2 + c)/3`.

Instead, you can calculate the sum recursively, then divide by `n` at the very end.

Comment: Thank you! Like at the end in main, printf("%d", aveg(s,n) / n); right?

Comment: @paulconiel Right, though I wouldn't name the function `aveg` since it would actually be just the sum.

Comment: Is there any other way to calculate this average using recursion?

Comment: @paulconiel Sure, just add the total number of elements as third parameter and divide `a[n-1]` by that before you add it to the recursion result.

Comment: I don't think I got it right, can you show me please?

Comment: @paulconiel https://stackoverflow.com/q/15801957/6699433

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively compute the mean (with zero based indices) as follows:

[image]

A possible implementation is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

double mean(const double a[],const size_t n)
{
  if(n==0)
    return 0;
  
  return (a[n-1]+(n-1)*mean(a,n-1))/n;
}

int main()
{
  double a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
  size_t n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a);
  
  printf("mean: %f\n",mean(a,n));
}
```

---

Compared to your solution:

```
return ((aveg(a, n - 1) + a[n-1]) /n);
```

you forgot a (n-1) factor:

```
return (a[n-1]+(n-1)*mean(a,n-1))/n;
```

Answer (score -1):

It works like calling itself (function) again and again until you get the true or your desire output.

Comment: This might explain basics about recursion. But it does not answer why this recursive function fails to produce desired output.